# _close file descriptor returned from _open_osfhandle over a HANDLE

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile( ... );
//...
int fd = _open_osfhandle( reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(h), 0 );
_commit( fd );

// _close(); // Not required
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fzwd5ss.aspx)

> The _close function closes the file associated with fd. The file
>   descriptor and the underlying OS file handle are closed. Thus, it is
>   not necessary to call CloseHandle if the file was originally opened
>   using the Win32 function CreateFile and converted to a file descriptor
>   using _open_osfhandle.

So according to the documentation, if I call `_close()` the underlying file `HANDLE` (my file) will close too, which is something that I don't want.

But I don't think this answers how I handle the file descriptor returned by `_open_osfhandle` and what happens to it. Is it ok if I just ignore the file descriptor and wait until the file is closed later ? Will file clean up (`CloseHandle()`) destroy the file descriptor too ?

Comment: Sounds like you need [DuplicateHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx) to pass a duplicate to `_open_osfhandle` which is fine to be closed by `_close` since your original handle to the same file is still alive.

Comment: In the windows API a HANDLE represents a reference to a kernel object (such as a file). If you want to have multiple references to a single object, you simply create multiple HANDLEs. e.g. via `DuplicateHandle`. This gives you a handle, to close at your leisure - and a handle to give to _open_ofshandle, to be closed by a balanced call to _close().

Comment: If the `_commit` call everything you do with the descriptor? Then why not use [`FlushFileBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx) on the handle, or open the file unbuffered, and don't have to worry about this specific problem?